# Составной MySQL запрос

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Как мне правильно составить составной MYSQL запрос выборки из двух таблиц по одному общему полю?
Если использовать INNER JOIN и USING, но он выводит только общие строки. Например,

```
SELECT * FROM nomenclature INNER JOIN description using(id);
+----+----------+---------------------+
| id | name     | description         |
+----+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | Книга    | Замечательная книга |
|  3 | Карандаш | Красный карандаш    |
+----+----------+---------------------+
```

А мне нужно, чтобы выводило следующим образом:

```
+----+----------+---------------------+
| id | name     | description         |
+----+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | Книга    | Замечательная книга |
|  2 | Ручка    |                     |
|  3 | Карандаш | Красный карандаш    |
+----+----------+---------------------+
```

Ну то есть, чтобы из таблицы nomenclature он выводил все записи и если есть соответствия в таблице description, то дописывал, а если нет, то просто оставлял поле пустым

Comment: а вы почитайте про join подробнее. там есть разные типы соединений

Comment: @teran можно ли использоваться COUNT(*) AS вместе с left join?

Comment: можно, join и т.п. лишь влияют на формирование набора данных из которого проводится выборка селектом. Что вы там в селекте напишите никак не связано с механизмами формирования этого набора.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM nomenclature LEFT JOIN description using(id);
Настоятельно советую почитать про left/right/inner join.

Comment: можно ли использоваться COUNT(*) AS вместе с left join?